# Is there any way to make jQueryUI sortable to clone items on alt or ctrl and don't clone without it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there any way to make jQueryUI sortable to clone items on alt or ctrl and don't clone without it? I did this with

```
$(this).sortable({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        if (event.altKey) {
            ui.item.before(ui.item.clone().removeAttr('style'));
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ...
    },
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        ...
    },
});
```

Maybe there is a better way by using `.sortable( "option", "helper", "clone" );`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, there is a way to make jQueryUI sortable to clone items on alt or ctrl keys and don't clone without it. Take a look at this **[How to make jQueryUI sortable to clone items using alt or ctrl keys and don’t clone without it?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-make-jqueryui-sortable-to-clone-items-using-alt-or-ctrl-keys-and-dont-clone-without-it/)** link this will help you to get it.
You must use the following code in your css

```
 display:block !important;
```

Because,When you use the clone option, the original item is hidden with style="display: none" when you start dragging. You could attach a handler to the sort event (or whatever event hides the original item) to re-show it. Everything should work for you then.
I hope this will help you more.

Comment: Yes, it's great help! Thanks!